# Adding Plugin-specific Fields with wp_insert_post()?

Tags: plugins, posts, plugin-all-in-one-seo

*(**Moderator's note:** The original title was "wp_insert_post() and plugins")*

I use `wp_insert_post()` like this:

```
 $my_post = array(
 'post_title' => 'title',
 'post_content' => $post,
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'post_author' => 1,
 'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $oldtime),
 'post_category' => array(3,4)

 );

 wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Everything works fine, but I want to use plugins like *"All in One SEO Pack"* I can't figure out how to save their custom fields. I tried this but it did not work:

```
 $my_post = array(
 'post_title' => 'title',
 'post_content' => $post,
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'post_author' => 1,
 'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $oldtime),
 'post_category' => array(3,4)
 'aiosp_description' => 'description',
 'aiosp_keywords' => 'keywords' // these (aiosp_) is from post edit page in WP (<input type="text" size="62" name="aiosp_keywords" value="keywords">)

 );

 wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

How can I save these fields? Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 3):

*@sorich87's* answer is 99% there. The difference is that [**All-in-One SEO Pack**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/) follows certain best practices and uses a prefix of `'_aioseop_'` on its meta keys. That makes the actual working code look more like this:

```
$my_post = array(
  'post_title' => 'title',
  'post_content' => $post,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post_author' => 1,
  'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $oldtime),
  'post_category' => array(3,4)
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

if( !is_wp_error($post_id) && $post_id > 0 ) {
  add_post_meta($post_id, '_aioseop_keywords', $keywords);
  add_post_meta($post_id, '_aioseop_description', $description);
  add_post_meta($post_id, '_aioseop_title', $title);
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the All-in-One SEO Pack specific records in the `wp_postmeta` table of my test system using Navicat for MySQL to view them:

[image: Screenshot of Post Meta records used by All-in-One SEO Pack]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101030-182611.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

All-in-one SEO data are saved as post metas. You will need to use `add_post_meta`:

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_title' => 'title',
    'post_content' => $post,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $oldtime),
    'post_category' => array(3,4)
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

if( !is_wp_error($post_id) && $post_id > 0 ) {
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'keywords', $keywords);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'description', $description);
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'title', $title);
}
```